# QGridLayout didn't maintain ColumnStretch ratio

Tags: qt4, qt-designer

How do I make QGridLayout maintain the set 'ColumnStretch' value for this [form](http://www.sendspace.com/file/tf5nsv).

In Windows, the caption label on top of treeview is small because the font is small and it doesn't push the first column of QGridLayout to take more space from the second column of QGridLayout.

In Ubuntu Linux though, I get the following:
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Since you know the reason for this behaviour, I guess you just want to hear some suggestions. These are my suggestions:

- Change the text, so it consumes less space - "Available specifications" sounds good to me
- Separate the long line on two rows
- Change the font size (you can change it only under linux, if you want)
- Combine the two labels on top in one, spanning on two columns, describing the form as a whole - "These are the available installed specifications and their description"

Hope this helps